# Dealing with a variable that is a number, but has greater meaning?

Tags: c++, variables, embedded-systems, data-types

I've been working on some embedded code that handles a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) radio.  BLE has 40 channels, numbered 0 through 39.  One function for the radio driver takes in the channel and sets the appropriate register with the correct setting.

The obvious function prototype was `SetChannel(uint8_t channel);`.  However, `uint8_t` can hold numbers from 0 to 255, but BLE only has 40 channels.  Any `channel` over 39 is invalid.

Which brings up my question: How should one handle a variable that's clearly a digit, but has a range less than the storage type?

I thought of using an enum, like this:

```
typdef enum channels
{
   Channel0,
   Channel1,
   Channel2,
   Channel3,
   ...
   Channel39
}BleChannel;
```

thus making the function prototype `SetChannel(BleChannel channel);`, but that just doesn't feel right when the type is clearly a number, but with a limited range.  Throwing an exception or otherwise terminating execution is not a great option due to this being an embedded device.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to assign the channel based on the MOD of the input?  In other words, divide the input value by 40 & use the remainder.  An input value between 0 and 39 would work as expected, and an input value of 41 would be assigned to channel 1.

Comment: On second thought, stick with enums.  Principle of least astonishment.

Comment: I would only use values Chanel0, Chanel1, Chanel2 etc. if the code was related to perfumes, not Bluetooth.

Comment: To clarify @gnasher729's comment, the enum labels should be `Channel0` ...

Comment: It's a number.  Use `uint8_t channel`, and treat numbers above 40 as an error.

Comment: It's too bad C++ and most of today's popular languages don't offer subranges.  Pascal has subranges, so you can just declare a type for `0..39`.

Comment: @ErikEidt Since Pascal allows values outside the range, its implementation of ranges is rather useless.

Comment: Do you treat channels as *numbers*? That is, is there logically a *successorship* relationship to the channels, or is the fact that two follows one unimportant? Do you never need to add, subtract, multiply or divide channels?

Comment: @EricLippert The channels just provide any easier way of expressing the carrier frequency.  Chanel 37 is 2402mhz, Chanel 0 is 2404mhz, and so on (specified by the standard).  It's easier to say "use channel 4" than "use 2428mhz".  The function is question essentially uses a lookup table to go from channel number to register setting.

Comment: @CHendrix: My point is: you say that the data is "clearly" numerical, but that is by no means clear to me. Look at it this way: suppose we renamed the forty channels "purple, square, manager, boxcar, ... , fish, soup", because it is easier to say "use channel soup".  Would you then have to encode somewhere in your program that "purple plus two is manager"?  If not, then the quantities are not actually numbers in the first place. They've just been given numbers arbitrarily out of convenience. But if you need to be able to say "channel 24 is four above channel 20", then they *are* numbers.

Comment: @EricLippert: Not to put too fine a point on this, but scanners (like the kind that people use to listen to police or fire radio) use a similar channel scheme.  The scanning occurs in numerical order.  It's almost certainly a number under the hood, unless you like figuring out how to sort the equivalent strings properly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Then it makes sense to encode the thing as a type you can do math on, rather than as an enumerated type, or string, or other object. I'd be inclined to make it an int unless there is a really good reason to restrict its size.

Comment: @CHendrix: What do you want to have happen if the method is presented with a number greater than 39?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's kind of what I was trying to figure out.  I don't have a good way of handling that condition, so I was thinking I could force it to use an enum and enforce type-checking with the C++ compiler.

Comment: So what you're telling me is that, if you decide to support a device with more or less channels than 40, you have to *recompile your program?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Well you'd already have to recompile the program because if you add channel 41, you have to add the frequency which it refers to also.

Comment: If you want compile-time support for this, it's going to have to be an enum.  If you're encoding the frequencies in code, you might as well use an enum.  But that would be akin to replacing the entire scanner instead of just replacing the crystals or entering a new frequency into the front panel.  Or maybe updating the firmware.  Is it your intention to update the firmware if a frequency changes?  cc @EricLippert

Comment: In case of doubt, go with the simplest solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers with limited range arise often enough that (IMO) it's worthwhile adding a type specifically to handle them. I've used something on this order quite a few times:

```
template <class T, T lower, T upper>
class bounded { 
    T val;
    void assure_range(T v) {
        if ( v < lower || upper <= v)
            throw std::range_error("Value out of range");
    }
public:
    bounded &operator=(T v) { 
        assure_range(v);
        val = v;
        return *this;
    }

    bounded(T const &v=T()) {
        assure_range(v);
        val = v;
    }

    operator T() { return val; }
};
```

You'd then do something on the order of:

```
using channel = bounded<uint8_t, 0, 39>;
```

If you just pass an `int8_t` (or whatever), you stand a good chance of ending up with two problems. One is that there's some route through the code where the value is used without its range being checked. The other is that you waste time repeatedly checking the range on the same value. Worse, if the code base is large at all, you can quite easily end up with *both* problems at the same time.

All the usual benefits of DRY apply here. By centralizing the range checking in one place, it's easy to assure that what we have is correct, easy to change in the future if needed, easy to be certain<sup>1</sup> that ranges are checked everywhere they need to be, without adding unnecessary checks of values that have already been checked. Most of all, of course, we get readable code, so what should have been a one-line functions don't end up with the real code buried somewhere under a layer of range checking that's irrelevant to the job at hand.

As far as using exception handling vs. not goes, the wording in the question ("Throwing an exception or otherwise terminating execution...") indicates that the OP has a mistaken belief about exceptions--that they lead to terminating the program. That's most assuredly not the case at all. An exception can terminate a program if it's never caught, but throwing and catching an exception can simply transfer the flow of execution from the code that detects a problem to code that knows how to handle that problem (without any intervening layers having to be aware of it at all, beyond being exception neutral). In short, this is exactly the sort of situation for which exception handling is designed, and absent a verifiable reason that it *really* can't be used here, it's clearly the right tool for the job.

It is, of course, possible that you always handle such an error in a single, specific way, or that you have a limited range of options that are all known at compile time. In the latter case, you can handle the error via a strategy class:

```
template <class T, T lower, T upper, class error> {

    // ...
    if ( v < lower || upper <= v)
        error("Value out of range");
```

Even if the released device only ever handles this error in one specific way (e.g., uses one specific channel) it can be worthwhile to use a template parameter rather than hard-coding the error handling directly into the code that detects the problem. There are at least a couple of obvious advantages:

1. You might change the one and only way of handling the problem.
2. It's easy to change the behavior during testing so such problems cause an immediate break to the debugger or at least log the problem.

---

<sup>1. Obviously here I'm discounting the possibility of somebody doing something like this:</sup>

```
uint8_t bad_channel = 127;
channel &c = *reinterpret_cast<channel *>(&bad_channel);
```

<sup>Given how C++ is defined, it's nearly impossible to keep people from shooting themselves in the feet if they try hard enough though. At the same time, `reinterpret_cast` (or an equivalent C-style cast) should always be examined with extreme care--it can be used to bypass almost *any* type-based assurances you try to give yourself.</sup>

Comment: Finally, a little sense among other garbage answers. Using c++ without exceptions is just stupid.

Comment: +1 this is an excellent answer.  While I think that adding special code to restrict the range of the type for this particular value is over-design, a general type to do this is very elegant and makes a lot of sense.  And once it exists, why not apply it in this case?  You have changed my mind about the best approach here.  Also, good discussion of exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't over-think this.**

- Use an integer.
- Test your code appropriately.

Now move on to the parts of the design that matter.

With all due respect, this is a very simple piece of code that seems incredibly unlikely to result in any bugs.  There is going to be some code that sets the channel, or increments or decrements it, and this code needs to only allow valid channels.  That is very simple to implement and you are going to do it correctly (given that you are clearly conscientious about this).  And assuming you have some reasonable testing in place, this will result in some very obvious test cases that would catch any problems.

It's the things you haven't thought of that are going to cause bugs, not this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a number with a limited range, treat it as a number. Make the type of the channel parameter int. Since you can't express the valid range by type, it doesn't make sense to even try. If passing any value other than 0 to 39 is a programming bug, add an assert in your development code so that it gets caught (passing int has the advantage that passing 256 will also be caught as an error); in the shipping product probably best to replace any invalid value with a valid one or rebooting; your job is to determine what is likely to cause less damage.

Comment: I have to disagree on nearly all counts. First and foremost, as my answer shows, you most certainly *can* represent the valid range by type. Essentially all your other arguments are based on that, rendering all invalid. The only part that's open to question is the top level, so to speak: what to do when/if something does receive an incorrect channel number (and since we don't know that, the proper answer is to throw an exception, so something at the proper level can make that determination).

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that your code can be tested via an automated test framework on your development machine and that the code can be structured such that the `SetChannel` function can be mocked/swapped during tests, I'd take the following approach:

1. Use the `SetChannel(uint8_t channel)` signature.
2. Do no defensive coding in that function; if eg 40 is passed in, then let the device fail, because,
3. Mock the `SetChannel` in your tests of the rest of the system with one that causes the test to fail if passed a number > 39 and then thoroughly test the rest of the code to ensure 40+ is never passed to the function.

By ensuring any calls to `SetChannel` behave themselves and only pass a valid channel number, the need to worry about out of range numbers goes away.

Comment: Despite the downvotes on this answer, David has a point.  *This is an embedded device,* so unless the channel numbers are coming from some outside source, this really ought to work properly without validation.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  There is no reason to constantly double check that you yourself are doing things correctly, and testing should easily cover this completely.  Apart from that, it's not clear that the failure mode for the defensive approach on an embedded device would be any better than the failure for a non-defensive approach.

Comment: I would prefer int versus uint8_t.  To me, uint8_t implies that the width of the variable is important but that's not the case here.

Comment: @kkrambo, very good point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an enum is ideal for two reasons:

- It doesn't actually enforce the validity
- Unless you're hardcoding channel numbers in your source code, it doesn't really give you any safety compared to an integer. You still need to parse user input into a channel identifier, which needs to handle invalid inputs anyways.

I'd consider a custom class which

- Has a function to construct it given an integer and/or string. This should be either an *explicit* constructor or a static method. Probably a static method, since that way you can *return* an error instead of throwing an exception.
- A way to enumerate all valid channels. This can be used to display the channels to select from in a UI (if you have one).
- The biggest advantage of this approach isn't that it enforces the range, but it makes accidentally passing some unrelated int as a channel identifier a compile time error. Since you don't need to do arithmetic on on the channel, the custom class doesn't need much boilerplate code either.
- That immutable object can have readonly properties for e.g. frequency.

Or just use an int or even string:

- It's the simplest approach and the alternatives don't buy much safety in practice.
- If different devices support a different number of channels, you can only check the validity when you associate it with a device.

Comment: `Or just use an int or string.` << this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Personally I'd probably go with a minimal custom class, just because it makes passing some other kind of integer a compile time error and not because it enforces the range.

Comment: It's not a compile-time problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Passing e.g. a device ID or a frequency in a place where the code expects a channel ID looks like a compile-time problem to me.

Comment: This isn't rocket science.  The folks who design radios don't think about things like this; they just hook it up and make it work.  They think all of our hand wringing about compile time errors is ridiculous (which it is).  Imagine a police scanner throwing an exception.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with this:

```
void SetChannel( const int channel );
```

then check the channel's value. If it is out of range, throw an exception.

Having an enum in this case is an awful solution, since it brings nothing into the code clarity.

Comment: Perfectly fine solution. Wait, it's exactly what I posted! Somebody doesn't get it.

Comment: "Throwing an exception or otherwise terminating execution is not a great option due to this being an embedded device"

Comment: @gnasher729 I posted 5 minutes ago, you 3. Therefore you posted exactly what I posted.

Comment: @DavidArno Are you kidding? I am programming embedded devices last 15 years, and been using them all the time. Even on a DSP having 32k memory.

Comment: @BЈовић, just quoting the OP. I'm not passing judgement on whether throwing exceptions on embedded devices is a good or bad thing. The OP explicitly stated they didn't want to do that though.

Comment: @DavidArno Ok, somehow I missed that (did he modify the question?). Because of [tag:c++] throwing an exception is the best option.